# Does a continuous function maps compact sets on product space to compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $y\in Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $t\in T\subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $T$ and $Y$ be compact sets. Define the set $S=\{ty\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid t\in T, y\in Y\}$. Is $S$ compact?

${\bf Question:}$ Is $S$ compact? I believe so and the following is my proof. Is my proof correct?

${\bf Proof:}$ Define a function $f:T\times Y\mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $f(t,y)=ty$. First, I will show that it is continuous.

$|t_ny_n-ty|=|t_ny_n+ty_n-ty_n-ty|\\
            \hspace{0.8in}=|(t_n-t)y_n+t(y_n-y)|\\
            \hspace{0.8in}\leq |t_n-t|\;\lVert y_n\rVert +|t|\;\lVert y_n-y\rVert\to 0$.\

If $T$ and $Y$ are compact, $T\times Y$ is compact. Thus, $S$ is a continuous image of a compact set. Therefore, it is compact.

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have *specific concerns* or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @MartinR I apologize, I am new here and I do not know a lot of the rules. I will try to be careful next time. Mainly my doubt is coming from lack of self-confidence.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much. I also think I should be able to argue the function is uniformly continuous as well. I am trying to prove it but have not succeeded yet. Is ty uniformly continuous as well? Perhaps I should post that as another question?

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, of course, sorry that was a dumb question. I was focusing on the function being sort of linear and totally forgot about the compactness.